# Next_page_token for new google maps places API - NearbySearch (Pagination)

Tags: pagination, google-places-api, google-nearby

I would like to use the New Places Nearby Search to find restaurants of a certain type. The max output is 20, but I would like to retrieve all results. In the old Places API it was possible through a next_page_token, but everything I tried with the new API didn't work (no next_page_token was found).

Is there any way to do this for the new places API (new in 2023), I can't seem to find any documentation about the new Pagination system.

Comment: 20 is too few for many use cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not a feature in the *Places API (New)* methods, there is a feature request you can subscribe to: [Implementing pagination or another solution for retrieving more than 20 results](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/314796720).